# dc-js: How to handle arrays of arrays to build line chart?

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have an array with objects (key, values):

```
var array = [ {
  key: 'Monday',
  values: [
    ['time', 123], ['someUnixTime', 1234] ...
  ]
} ,
.... // here more same objects
];
```

I don't know how to handle groups and dimensions, I mean, dimension should return an exact value, but what about in case I have an array of arrays to return?

```
var ndx = crossfilter(array);
var dimensionByTime = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
      return d.values; // I need here first element of array
    }); 

var dimensionValueByTime = dimension.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
      return d.key; // I need here 2nd element of array
    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The values look like they are just key/value pairs which could as well be properties of the objects in your array. Is there any reason you can't preprocess your data? I think this would be safer than accessing them by index, and then your dimension and group definitions will be a lot simpler.

Comment: Yes, thank you. It's much better to preprocess such as data. After some simple dividing loops, I could get an array of objects: `[ { key: '', val1: '', val2: ''}, { ...} ]`